# Convert a half width string in java to full width

Tags: java

Consider a half width string 'Hello'. What java library should I use to get its full width equivalent which is 'Ｈｅｌｌｏ'.

Any sample code is also appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details about half string and full string ?

Comment: The magic number seems to be 65248: Normal "H" has char value 72, Full-width "Ｈ" has the char value of 65320. So the full width characters seem to be 65248 higher than the normal letters. So one possible solution would be to convert your Sting to a char array, then add 65248 to all char values for creating your Full-Width string (via Stringbuilder or stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half and full width characters differ by **65248**. So all you need to do is simply add that number to each character.

Example with stream:

```
public static String toFullWidth(String halfWidth) {
  return halfWidth.chars()
    .map(c -> c + 65248)
    .collect(
      StringBuilder::new, 
      (builder, c) -> builder.append((char) c), 
      StringBuilder::append
    )
    .toString();
}
```

Example with loop:

```
public static String toFullWidthWithLoop(String halfWidth) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : halfWidth.toCharArray()) {
    builder.append((char) (c + 65248));
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```